# Displaying an initial value of and empty string before displaying the databse values in the combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle11g

I would like your help in allowing the combobox to display an initial value of and empty string before taking the column values from database. Is there anyways i can do it. This is what i tried and it is working only the problem was it is not displaying and empty string initially, it display the value in the database table instead.

```
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select subject_code from subjectinfo where subject_code like '%'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        oda.Fill(dt);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "subject_code";
        comboBox1.Text = "";
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine custom items to a combobox which is already bound to datasource.
Instead you can set `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1` which will show empty text and none of the values selected initially.

Comment: thanks sir, it really help. I try to vote u 1 but cant as they said need 15 reputation else sure i will do 1.

Comment: if this solves the purpose, then u can accept it as answer